# Does “#includes” position matter on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I find my query is taking too long to load so I'm wondering if the position of the includes matters.

Example A:

```
people = Person.where(name: 'guillaume').includes(:jobs)
```

Example B:

```
people = Person.includes(:jobs).where(name: 'guillaume')
```

Is example A faster because I should have fewer people's jobs to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

ActiveRecord builds your query and as long as you don't need the records, it won't send the final SQL query to the database to fetch them. The 2 queries you pasted are identical.

Whenever in doubt, you can always open up `rails console`, write your queries there and observe the queries printed out. In your example it would be something like:

```
SELECT  "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "guillaume"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."person_id" = 1
```

in both of the cases.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.